# JSS deploy vueJs - then I need to manually Unprotect Layout to add my placeholders

Tags: presentation, placeholders, jss

Currently, each time I'm doing deploying jss using

```
jss deploy package -c -d
```

I need to manually unprotect the Item of my App Layout to include my placeholders.

[image]

Any ideas how to stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholders for the layout item are handled a bit differently than placeholders defined within your JS components because they are the top level placeholders that Layout Service needs to render.

Two potential solutions:

1. Create a component that is assigned to the `main` placeholder. Then in that component declare your `PH__footer`, `PH__header` and `PH__main` placeholders. Be sure to update your manifest declarations accordingly.
2. In the `/sitecore/config/jss-basic-app-vue-web.config` file in your JS app, find the `/configuration/sitecore/javaScriptServices/apps/app` node and add the following attribute:
   `rootPlaceholders="main,PH__footer,PH__header,PH__main"`
   This will tell the import service which placeholders should be defined for the JSS app layout. Be sure to deploy/copy your modified config file to your Sitecore instance after making the change.

For #2, the `app` config node inherits default values from the app definition found in `/App_Config/Sitecore/JavaScriptServices/Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config` in your Sitecore instance.

Also note: these approaches are valid for the other JS libs as well, e.g. React, Angular.